# a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'

Tags: python, file, nlp

[image]

As you can see this parameter's kind is 'bytes' already,
however the type error also exist. 
Who can tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image!

Comment: Iterating over bytes gives you integers. Just use `fW.write(byte)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`writelines` expects an iterable, so it will iterate on your `bytes` object, and each item it iterates on is an `int`.

You probably mean to `write` your `bytes` object instead.